Why the answer is 4?
I am beginner and found the following JS code. I am unable to understand why the output 4.
Can someone please help?


function func1() {
  return 2;
}

function func2() {
  return 4;
}

let a = (func1(), func2());

console.log(a)



I want to understand why the output is 4.

Comma Operator (MDN)

A good title summarizes the problem and also helps to distinguish your question from other similar questions on this site.  Your title is more like click-bait in that it is intriguing but lacking any essence of the real question. In fact, reading the body of your question, you don't even elaborate on why you think the output should or shouldn't be 4.  I'm guessing you're confused about how the comma operator works.

In JavaScript, the comma operator evaluates all expressions in a sequence and returns the result of the last one. In your code:
let a = (func1(), func2());

func1() returns 2, but its result is ignored. func2() returns 4, which is assigned to a. Thus, a is 4, and console.log(a) outputs 4.

"evaluates all expressions in a sequence and returns the result of the last one" - while factually true, it's misleading.  let b; b = func1(), func2(); and the result of b will be 2 (not 4).  The , has lower precedence over =, so the = occurs first before the comma.  It gives 4 due to the brackets, which have higher precedence.

Got it, it's good to know this information, thank you.
